# how to handle errors thrown in Request::capture() in index.php?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, error-handling

- Laravel Version:  8 (last version)
- PHP Version: 7.4.10
- Database Driver & Version: MySql 5.6

#### Description:

Exceptions that are thrown in `index.php`  in `Request::capture()` is not handled by the error handler `\App\Exceptions\Handler.php`.

In my case: there is an antivirus in the server which deletes any infected uploaded file. When the user uploads an infected file. what happens is:

1. the user uploads file.
2. PHP puts the file path in the global request.
3. the antivirus deletes the file.
4. Symfony tries to construct the file here `SymfonyRequest::createFromGlobals()`
5. Symfony checks the file here `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php`:

```
public function __construct(string $path, bool $checkPath = true)
{
  if ($checkPath && !is_file($path)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
  }

  parent::__construct($path);
}
```

6. exception is thrown and it's going to show it in the browser (security issue)
   `Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: The file "/tmp/php6CKu5H" does not exist in /home/vagrant/code/eskan/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php on line 35`

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Set up fresh Laravel installment.
2. throw the error in `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php` like this:

```
public function __construct(string $path, bool $checkPath = true)
{
  throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
  if ($checkPath && !is_file($path)) {
  }

  parent::__construct($path);
}
```

Note: any thrown error in `Request::capture()` can have the same case.
[my issue link in laravel repo](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36024)

Comment: Yes, I can also get the issue that the exception is not handled by the exception handler but I don't see the exception in the browser either I just the the chrome generic 500 error. However I do agree that this is not a framework issue. Since the issue is arising from `public/index.php` and that file is in the `laravel/laravel` project then it might be more appropriate to point out in that project that exceptions in the index are not handled by the exception handler.